# How to pass extra variable to function if conditions are met

Tags: python, python-3.x, one-liner

Say I have the following python code:

```py
hp = 0
if 'header' is in paramdict.keys():
    hp = paramdict['header']
mydf = [pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet, header = hp) for sheet in xlsx.sheet_names]
```

I only want to pass `header` if it's in `paramdict`. (default value is 0)

Is there a better way to do this, or one that's easier on the eyes / takes up less space? I've tried fstrings and eval but haven't been able to get them to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict` has a `.get` method that allows you to pass a default value that gets returned if the `key` is **not present** in the `dict`

```
hp = paramdict.get('header', 0)
mydf = [pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet, header=hp) for sheet in xlsx.sheet_names]
```

Here's an example,

```
>>> d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
>>> d
{'one': 1, 'two': 2}
>>> d.get('one', 'Nope, not here')
1
>>> d.get('three', 'Nope, not here')
'Nope, not here'
```

Comment: Great! Is there a way to do this without knowing the default value? (Ideally not calling any default values to avoid very long and unreadable function calls for functions with many optional parameters.)

Comment: The default default value is `None`, i.e., if you don't pass the second arg to `get`, it returns `None` when the key is not present. If you don't have a specific default value, I'm afraid you'll have to come up with some logic to handle that case.